# How to convert specific numbers stored in an array into specific phrases for me to print

Tags: python

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSsip.png)

Now for some context i am somewhat new to python and use idle 3.8.10 and what i am doing is allowing the user to input where they would like to volunteer by picking a number from a list but when i print it i need it to convert the specific numbers to specific phrases.

the specific number to phrase conversions would be.

1  Pier entrance gate
2  Gift shop
3  Painting and decorating
4  Not to volunteer

then i need to be able to print vaArr but each number will equal the certain phrases.

Thanks,
lamby.

The array name is currently vaArr and it was inputted as va

```
vaArr =[]

va = input("Enter the member's chosen volunteering area. 1 for the peir 
enterance, 2 for the gift shop, 3 for painting and decorating, 4 if you 
do not wish to volunteer and press q to quit: ")

while len(va) == 0:
    va = input("You must enter the member's chosen volunteering area. 1 
for the peir enterance, 2 for the gift shop, 3 for painting and 
decorating, 4 if you do not wish to volunteer and press q to quit: ")

while va.upper() != "Q":
    vaArr.append(va)
    va = input("Enter the next member's chosen volunteering area. 1 for 
the peir enterance, 2 for the gift shop, 3 for painting and decorating, 
4 if you do not wish to volunteer and press q to quit: ")
    while len(va) == 0:
        va = input("You must enter the next member's chosen volunteering 
area. 1 for the peir enterance, 2 for the gift shop, 3 for painting and 
decorating, 4 if you do not wish to volunteer and press q to quit: ")
```

Comment: Edit your question, and include your code (format it as code using the toolbar).

Comment: Use a dictionary where the keys are the user input (number) and associated values are the phrases

Comment: Just use a list: `phrases = ["Pier entrance gate", "Gift shop", "Painting and decorating", "Not to volunteer"]` and then use the user input to access the list. i.e. `phrases[3-1]` will give `"Painting and decorating"`

Comment: @trincot i do apologise for missing out the code in the original but i have added it now.  and i will try the list

Comment: You may consider to just ask the user to enter all the desired options in one go, without looping.

Comment: @trincot that could work but you need to be able to input more than one person for section but could possibly make the whole thing a big loop

Comment: I don't see the aspect of person in your question, but yes you would repeat the process for each person.

Comment: @trincot its an assignment for school and the task is very weird i will link the assignment above

Comment: @trincot the assignment is the image

Comment: I see. You have a lot more to do then ,-)

Comment: wish me luck :)

Comment: once i have finished this i got 2 more tasks :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this simple example helps you to get going:

#### Code

```py
items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach"]

# Just formatting the message a bit
listed_items = f"\n".join([f" [{i + 1}] {f}" for i, f in enumerate(items)])
message = f"Please select a fruit:\n{listed_items}\nChoice: "

index = None

while not isinstance(index, int):
    try:
        # Try to convert the input to an integer
        index = int(input(message))
    except ValueError as e:
        # If int() failed, we can catch the error and tell
        # the user to try again.
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a integer number.")
        continue

    if index < 1 or index > len(items):
        # Make sure we got a valid number
        print(f"Please enter a number between 1 and {len(items)}")
        index = None

# If we succeeded we can access index like so:
print(f"You selected: \"{items[index - 1]}\"")
```

#### Output

```
Please select a fruit:
 [1] Apple
 [2] Banana
 [3] Peach
Choice: 1
You selected: "Apple"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary. The numbers would be the key and the phrases would be the values. For example:

```
dic = {'1' : "Pier entrance gate", '2': "Gift shop", '3': "Painting and decorating", '4': "Not to volunteer"}
```

Then print the phrase based on the input. Let's assume your input number is stored in *va*. Then you should probably print the value for the *va* key in dictionary:

```
print(dic[va])
```

Example:

```
print(dic['1'])

Pier entrance gate  # the printed result
```

Comment: how could i use an array to print more than one of them

Comment: A dict with sequential integer keys is just an elaborate list... This can just be a list accessed with `index-1`